# ggplot reflect plot about y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to reflect a plot made with ggplot through the y-axis?

I would like to go from this:
[image]

to this:
[image]
(Obviously without reflecting the axis labels!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a function `scale_x_reverse()` that should do what you want.

Comment: And then adjust Y-axis position with `scale_y_continuous(position = "right")`