# x-axis in reverse order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've used the following way to create 3 histograms. The 4th one has suddenly a reverse order on the x-axis. However, there's nothing (at least nothing I know about) in the snippet that should affect the order.

[image: The x-axis is expected to start with the lowest value on the left]

The x-axis is expected to start with the lowest value on the left.

Here's the R code:

```
df <- mydata %>% mutate(length.class=cut(mydata$count,breaks = c(1,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000),include.lowest=TRUE,dig.lab=8)) %>% group_by(length.class) %>% summarise(count = n())
dftext <- as.data.frame(table(df$length.class))
colnames(dftext)[1] <- "x"
dftext$lab[dftext$x == "[1,10]"] <- 1063393
dftext$lab[dftext$x == "(10,100]"] <- 65986
dftext$lab[dftext$x == "(100,1000]"] <- 3206
dftext$lab[dftext$x == "(1000,10000]"] <- 386
dftext$lab[dftext$x == "(10000,100000]"] <- 32
dftext$lab[dftext$x == "(100000,1000000]"] <- 0
dftext$lab[dftext$x == "(1000000,10000000]"] <- 1

df$count[df$length.class == "(1000000,10000000]"] <- 1.1  // To make its bar visible

fmt <- function(decimals=0){
    function(x) format(x,scientific = FALSE)
}

ggplot(df,aes(length.class,count)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity",width=0.9,fill="#999966") + scale_y_log10(labels = fmt()) + labs(x="", y="") + geom_text(data=dftext, aes(x=x, y=2, label=lab), size = 6) + theme(text = element_text(size=20)) +
    theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
          panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "grey"),
          panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "grey"),
          panel.background = element_blank(),
          axis.title.x = element_text(margin=margin(t = 15, unit = "pt")),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

What is causing the reverse order and how can I get rid of it?

**Edit:**
You guys are fast! :) The answer of @mark-peterson looks pretty solid, however I didn't get any working results with it though.
Here's the requested data:
[mydata.csv](http://www.file-upload.net/download-11941284/mydata.csv.html)

Comment: It would help if you gave a sample `mydata` so your code will work

Comment: In the meantime, try adding `scale_x_reverse()`. It's ready-made for this. This might be [the best duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127035/ggplot-reflect-plot-about-y-axis/29127211#29127211)

Comment: I get a "Harmful Programs" warning when I go to download the data. Can you `dput` a subset that results in the plotting error instead?

Comment: I uploaded it to another site: https://ufile.io/dd056 It's just a textfile. Does it help?

Comment: I did get it from there -- I like helping on SO, I am just not willing to risk a malicious site to do it ;)  I did get my solution working on your data, though it still requires @aosmith 's answer to get the right sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two datasets have the same *levels* of the factors `length.class` and `x`, but there is no row for `(100000,1000000]` in your first dataset, df.  This is because `summarise` has no `drop = FALSE` option to keep all levels of a factor in the dataset regardless of if they have any observations.

As you built your plot using the dataset with fewer factors in the rows, it looks like *ggplot2* gets confused when you add the new layer that has more factor levels and things get ordered oddly.

A fix is to make sure the x axis doesn't drop any factor levels by using `drop = FALSE` in `scale_x_discrete`.  That way you will be working with the same factor levels for the x axis for both datasets and things won't get mis-ordered.

```
+ scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

Comment: So simple and it works! I didn't think about it to be a problem, as it wasn't one before. Maybe because the labeling changed. Thanks for helping me again. You should consider writing a R book ;)

Answer (score 1):

When given text labels, `geom_bar` converts to a factor and sorts the bars. My guess it that alphabetical and numerical matched up for your previous uses, but did not for this one. I thought that @Pierre was right about `scale_x_reverse()`, but it doesn't appear to work on factors. Instead, you will need to set the factor orders yourself. Without sample data, it is hard to help do that.

A better question, however, is why you are doing so much work by hand here. The tools exist to automate much of your set up, with the added benefit of reducing errors and sorting the factor correctly. For example, with some reproducible data:

```
temp <- data.frame(a = 1:999)

temp$binned <-
  cut(temp$a, 10^(0:3), include.lowest = TRUE)

forText <-
  table(temp$binned) %>%
  as.data.frame()

ggplot(temp, aes(x = binned)) +
  geom_bar() +
  geom_text(data = forText
            , aes(x = Var1
                  , y = 75
                  , label = Freq))
```

[image]

If you just want a picture of the distribution, you can be even faster with a histogram:

```
ggplot(temp, aes(a)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_x_log10()
```

[image]

(Also, in the future, try to strip down to an MWE -- no need to include lots of `theme` settings if they are not germane to the problem.)

Using the posted data, I got the plot to work with my approach above. Note that you would need to add the additional theme and scale arguments. You also need to make use of @aosmith's answer about the missing value. (Which, I think, means that @aosmith's answer actually answers your question, while mine may be just good advice for how to do this more quickly.)

```
mydata$binned <-
  cut(mydata$count,breaks = c(1,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000),include.lowest=TRUE,dig.lab=8)

forText <-
  table(mydata$binned) %>%
  as.data.frame()

ggplot(mydata, aes(x = binned)) +
  geom_bar() +
  geom_text(data = forText
            , aes(x = Var1
                  , y = 75
                  , label = Freq)) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately it doesn't work. Your short cut command creates a 3rd column on my data frame which has 3 NAs for [1,10] until (100,1000] and then starts with (100,1e+03] for the row (1000,100000] down to [1,10] for the highest row (1m,10m].

Comment: What do you mean by MWE? Google couldn't help me on that.

Comment: MWE is a Minimal Working Example. Here is the [Stack Overflow description](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) is the R specific information.  The cut points that I used are specific to my example data. If you have lower (or higher) values, you will need to add them - you should be able to use the same breaks as in your original answer.